# Можно ли вызвать создать объект AsyncTask в классе Fragment?

Tags: android, java

Как вызвать создать объект AsyncTask в классе Fragment?

У меня не получается. При попытке `mt = new MyTask();` - ошибка:

> No enclosing instance of type FragmentLayout.TitlesFragment is accessible. 
>   Must qualify the allocation with an enclosing instance of type FragmentLayout.
>   TitlesFragment (e.g. x.new A() where x is an instance of FragmentLayout.TitlesFragment).

А вот это без ошибки:  `mt.execute();`

Ведь, как я понимаю, класс Fragment не является UI Thread, а значит и вызывать объект AsyncTask из него нельзя? Наследованный от AsyncTask класс описан в классе Activity, а объект AsyncTask мне нужно вызвать из Fragment.

Код полностью:

FragmentLayout.java (см. класс MyTask)

```
package com.ftdi.javad2xxdemo;

import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.Fragment;
import android.app.FragmentTransaction;
import android.app.ListFragment;
import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.IntentFilter;
import android.content.res.Configuration;
import android.hardware.usb.UsbManager;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.util.TypedValue;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.AbsListView;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.ScrollView;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.ftdi.j2xx.D2xxManager;

//import com.ftdi.javad2xxdemo.DeviceUARTFragment.MyTask;

// my
import android.widget.Toast;
import android.app.ListActivity;
// end of mine

public class FragmentLayout extends Activity {





    public static D2xxManager ftD2xx = null;
    public static int currect_index = 0;
    public static int old_index = -1;

    private static Fragment currentFragment = null;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        try {
            ftD2xx = D2xxManager.getInstance(this);
        } catch (D2xxManager.D2xxException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.fragment_layout/*device_manager*/); 
        SetupD2xxLibrary();

        /*
        Context context = getApplicationContext();
        Toast toast = Toast.makeText(context, "Hello toast!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
        toast.show();
        */


        IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter();
        filter.addAction(UsbManager.ACTION_USB_DEVICE_ATTACHED);
        filter.addAction(UsbManager.ACTION_USB_DEVICE_DETACHED);
        filter.setPriority(500);
        this.registerReceiver(mUsbReceiver, filter);   
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        this.unregisterReceiver(mUsbReceiver);
        super.onDestroy();
    }

    public static class DetailsActivity extends Activity {

        Map<Integer, Fragment> act_map = new HashMap<Integer, Fragment>();

        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

            if (getResources().getConfiguration().orientation
                    == Configuration.ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE) {
                // If the screen is now in landscape mode, we can show the
                // dialog in-line with the list so we don't need this activity.
                finish();
                return;
            }

            if (savedInstanceState == null) {
                // During initial setup, plug in the details fragment.
                Fragment f = act_map.get(currect_index);
                if (f == null)
                {
                    switch (currect_index)
                    {
                        case 0:
                            f = new DeviceInformationFragment(this , ftD2xx);
                            break;
                        case 1:
                            f = new DeviceStatusFragment(this , ftD2xx);
                            break;
                        case 2:
                            f = new DevicePIDVIDFragment(this , ftD2xx);
                            break;
                        case 3:
                            f = new MiscFragment(this , ftD2xx);
                            break;
                        case 4:
                            f = new OpenDeviceFragment(this , ftD2xx);
                            break;
                        case 5:
                            f = new DeviceUARTFragment(this , ftD2xx);
                            break;
                        case 6:
                            f = new DeviceFileTransferFragment(this , ftD2xx);
                            break;
                        case 7:
                            f = new EEPROMFragment(this , ftD2xx);
                            break;
                        case 8:
                            f = new EEPROMUserAreaFragment(this , ftD2xx);
                            break;
                        case 9:
                            f = new FT4232HTestFragment(this , ftD2xx);
                            break;
                        case 10:
                            f = new FT2232HTestFragment(this , ftD2xx);
                            break;
                        case 11:
                            f = new RS232PinConfigFragment(this , ftD2xx);
                            break;  
                        case 12:
                            f = new MPSEFragment(this , ftD2xx);
                            break;
                        case 13:
                            f = new FtdiEventFragment(this , ftD2xx);
                            break;  
                        default:
                            f = new DetailsFragment();
                            break;
                    }

                    act_map.put(currect_index, f);
                    f.setArguments(getIntent().getExtras());
                    getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().add(android.R.id.content, f).commit();
                }

                currentFragment = f;
            }
        }
    }

    private void SetupD2xxLibrary () {
        /*
        PackageManager pm = getPackageManager();

        for (ApplicationInfo app : pm.getInstalledApplications(0)) {
          Log.d("PackageList", "package: " + app.packageName + ", sourceDir: " + app.nativeLibraryDir);
          if (app.packageName.equals(R.string.app_name)) {
              System.load(app.nativeLibraryDir + "/libj2xx-utils.so");
              Log.i("ftd2xx-java","Get PATH of FTDI JIN Library");
              break;
          }
        }
        */
        // Specify a non-default VID and PID combination to match if required

        if(!ftD2xx.setVIDPID(0x0403, 0xada1))
            Log.i("ftd2xx-java","setVIDPID Error");

    }

    /**
     * This is the "top-level" fragment, showing a list of items that the
     * user can pick.  Upon picking an item, it takes care of displaying the
     * data to the user as appropriate based on the currrent UI layout.
     */

    public static class TitlesFragment extends ListFragment {
        boolean mDualPane;
        int mCurCheckPosition = 0;
       //  int mDualPaneIndex = -1;
        // public static D2xx ftD2xx;
        // Context TitlesFragmentContext = this.;
        Map<Integer, Fragment> map = new HashMap<Integer, Fragment>();

        // public void setTitlesFragment(Context parentContext)
        // {
        //  TitlesFragmentContext = parentContext;
            // ftD2xx = ftdid2xx;
        // }

        public TitlesFragment() {

        }

        @Override
        public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);

            // Populate list with our static array of titles.

            setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity(),
                    android.R.layout.simple_list_item_activated_1, FtdiModeListInfo.TITLES));

            /*
            ArrayAdapter a = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity(), android.R.layout.simple_list_item_activated_1, FtdiModeListInfo.TITLES);
            setListAdapter(a);
            */

            // Check to see if we have a frame in which to embed the details
            // fragment directly in the containing UI.
            View detailsFrame = getActivity().findViewById(R.id.details);

            mDualPane = detailsFrame != null && detailsFrame.getVisibility() == View.VISIBLE;

            if (savedInstanceState != null) {
                // Restore last state for checked position.
                mCurCheckPosition = savedInstanceState.getInt("curChoice", 0);
            }

            if (mDualPane) {
                // In dual-pane mode, the list view highlights the selected item.
                getListView().setChoiceMode(AbsListView.CHOICE_MODE_SINGLE);
                getListView().setVisibility(8); // GONE
                // Make sure our UI is in the correct state.
                showDetails(mCurCheckPosition);
            }
        }





        class MyTask extends AsyncTask<String, Integer, Void> {


            @Override
            protected Void doInBackground(String... urls) {
                    publishProgress();
                    onProgressUpdate();
                return null;
            }


            @Override
            protected void onProgressUpdate(Integer... values) {
              super.onProgressUpdate(values);
              progressBar.incrementProgressBy(10);  
              //Toast.makeText(DeviceUARTContext, "AsyncTask", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }

         }



        @Override
        public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
            super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
            outState.putInt("curChoice", mCurCheckPosition);
        }

        @Override
        public void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
            showDetails(position);
        }

        /**
         * Helper function to show the details of a selected item, either by
         * displaying a fragment in-place in the current UI, or starting a
         * whole new activity in which it is displayed.
         */
        void showDetails(int index) {
            mCurCheckPosition = index;
            currect_index = index;
            // Log.i("FragmentLayout","index = " + Integer.toString(index));
            // Log.i("FragmentLayout","mDualPaneIndex = " + Integer.toString(mDualPaneIndex));
            if (mDualPane) {
                // We can display everything in-place with fragments, so update
                // the list to highlight the selected item and show the data.
                getListView().setItemChecked(index, true);
                Fragment f = map.get(index);
                if (f == null) {
                    switch (index) {
                    case 0:
                        //f = new DeviceInformationFragment(getActivity() , ftD2xx);
                        //f = new DeviceManagerFragment(getActivity() , ftD2xx);
                        f = new DeviceUARTFragment(getActivity() , ftD2xx);
                        break;
                    case 1:
                        f = new DeviceStatusFragment(getActivity() , ftD2xx);
                        break;
                    case 2:
                        f = new DevicePIDVIDFragment(getActivity() , ftD2xx);
                        break;
                    case 3:
                        f = new MiscFragment(getActivity() , ftD2xx);
                        break;
                    case 4:
                        f = new OpenDeviceFragment(getActivity() , ftD2xx);
                        break;
                    case 5:
                        f = new DeviceUARTFragment(getActivity() , ftD2xx);
                        break;
                    case 6:
                        f = new DeviceFileTransferFragment(getActivity() , ftD2xx);
                        break;
                    case 7:
                        f = new EEPROMFragment(getActivity() , ftD2xx);
                        break;
                    case 8:
                        f = new EEPROMUserAreaFragment(getActivity() , ftD2xx);
                        break;
                    case 9:
                        f = new FT4232HTestFragment(getActivity() , ftD2xx);
                        break;
                    case 10:
                        f = new FT2232HTestFragment(getActivity() , ftD2xx);
                    break;  
                    case 11:
                        f = new RS232PinConfigFragment(getActivity() , ftD2xx);
                        break;
                    case 12:
                        f = new MPSEFragment(getActivity() , ftD2xx);
                        break;
                    case 13:
                        f = new FtdiEventFragment(getActivity() , ftD2xx);
                        break;  
                    default:
                        f = new DetailsFragment();
                        break;
                    }

                    map.put(index, f);
                    Bundle args = new Bundle();
                    args.putInt("index", index);
                    f.setArguments(args);
                }

                currentFragment = f;

                if ( currect_index != old_index ) {
                FragmentTransaction ft = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
                ft.replace(R.id.details, f);
                ft.setTransition(FragmentTransaction.TRANSIT_FRAGMENT_FADE);
                ft.commit();
                }
                old_index = currect_index;
            }
            else
            {
                // Otherwise we need to launch a new activity to display
                // the dialog fragment with selected text.
                Intent intent = new Intent();
                intent.setClass(getActivity(), DetailsActivity.class);
                intent.putExtra("index", index);
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        }
    }

    /**
     * This is the secondary fragment, displaying the details of a particular
     * item.
     */
    public static class DetailsFragment extends Fragment {
        /*
        public static DetailsFragment newInstance(int index) {
            DetailsFragment f = new DetailsFragment();
            // Supply index input as an argument.
            Bundle args = new Bundle();
            args.putInt("index", index);
            f.setArguments(args);

            return f;
        }
        */
        public DetailsFragment() {

        }

        public int getShownIndex() {
            return getArguments().getInt("index", -1);
        }

        @Override
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            if (container == null) {
                // We have different layouts, and in one of them this
                // fragment's containing frame doesn't exist.  The fragment
                // may still be created from its saved state, but there is
                // no reason to try to create its view hierarchy because it
                // won't be displayed.  Note this is not needed -- we could
                // just run the code below, where we would create and return
                // the view hierarchy; it would just never be used.
                return null;
            }

            ScrollView scroller = new ScrollView(getActivity());
            TextView text = new TextView(getActivity());
            int padding = (int)TypedValue.applyDimension(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP,
                    4, getActivity().getResources().getDisplayMetrics());
            text.setPadding(padding, padding, padding, padding);
            scroller.addView(text);
            text.setText(FtdiModeListInfo.DIALOGUE[getShownIndex()]);
            return scroller;
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onNewIntent(Intent intent)
    {
        String action = intent.getAction();
        if(UsbManager.ACTION_USB_DEVICE_ATTACHED.equals(action))        
        {
            switch (currect_index) 
            {
            case 4:
                ((OpenDeviceFragment)currentFragment).notifyUSBDeviceAttach(intent);
                break;
            case 5:
                ((DeviceUARTFragment)currentFragment).notifyUSBDeviceAttach();
                break;
            case 7:
                ((EEPROMFragment)currentFragment).notifyUSBDeviceAttach();              
                break;
            case 8:
                ((EEPROMUserAreaFragment)currentFragment).notifyUSBDeviceAttach();              
                break;              
            default:
                break;
            }
        }
    }

    /***********USB broadcast receiver*******************************************/
    private final BroadcastReceiver mUsbReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() 
    {
        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) 
        {
            String TAG = "FragL";           
            String action = intent.getAction();
            if(UsbManager.ACTION_USB_DEVICE_DETACHED.equals(action))
            {
                Log.i(TAG,"DETACHED...");

                if (currentFragment != null)
                {
                    switch (currect_index) 
                    {

                    case 5:
                        ((DeviceUARTFragment)currentFragment).notifyUSBDeviceDetach();
                        break;
                    default:
                        //((DeviceInformationFragment)currentFragment).onStart();
                        break;
                    }
                }           
            }
        }   
    };
}
```

DeviceUARTFragment.java (сокращён, весь не влазит). см. //mt = new MyTask();
                                        //mt.execute();
    в обработчике кнопки ReadDataBut

```
@SuppressLint("ValidFragment") public class DeviceUARTFragment extends Fragment{
// Empty Constructor
public DeviceUARTFragment()
{
}

/* Constructor */
public DeviceUARTFragment(Context parentContext , D2xxManager ftdid2xxContext)
{
    DeviceUARTContext = parentContext;
    ftdid2xx = ftdid2xxContext;
}

public int getShownIndex() {
    return getArguments().getInt("index", 5);
}











@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
    Bundle savedInstanceState) {



        ReadDataBut = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.button12);
    ReadDataBut.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            clickedButton = v.getId();


            // пробудить Гобой
            /*
            9600бит/сек / 8 = 1200байт/сек
            время пересылки 1-го байта: 1/1200 = 0,83мс
            число циклов: 22сек / 0.83мс = 27000    
            минус время операции в for
            */
            //progressBar = (ProgressBar) view.findViewById(R.id.progressBar1);
            //progressBar.setProgress(33);





            byte[] wakeUpCommand = {0x55};


            for(int i=0; i<20000; i++)
            {
                ftDev.write(wakeUpCommand, wakeUpCommand.length);
            }

            //progressBar.setProgress(0);
            //percent.setText("Считывание архива... ");
            //try{


            /*
            }
            catch( Exception e){
                Toast.makeText(DeviceUARTContext, "e: "+e, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
            */

            try {
                Thread.sleep(500);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }






            for (int i=0; i<packetIntervals.length; i++)
            {
                packetIntervals[i] = (char)(i*packetSize);
            }


            /*
            addrCnt = 0;
            sendRequest();
            //fillArchive();
            addrCnt++;
            */



            for (int i=0; i<packetIntervals.length; i++)
            {



                readPacket[9] = (byte)(packetIntervals[i] & 0xFF);
                readPacket[10] = (byte)((packetIntervals[i] >> 8) & 0xFF);

                readPacket[readPacket.length - 1] = (byte)((getLRC(readPacket) >> 8) & 0xFF);
                readPacket[readPacket.length - 2] = (byte)(getLRC(readPacket) & 0xFF);




                ftDev.write(readPacket, readPacket.length);


                try {
                    Thread.sleep(2500);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }


                // посылка пришла
                answ_buff_cnt = 0;

                //mt = new MyTask();
                //mt.execute();



                if ( ((byte)((getLRC(answer_buffer) >> 8) & 0xFF) != answer_buffer[answer_buffer.length-1]) ||
                      ((byte)(getLRC(answer_buffer) & 0xFF) != answer_buffer[answer_buffer.length-2]) ) 
                {
                      Toast.makeText(DeviceUARTContext, "Ошибка принятых данных. Начните чтение ПЗУ снова", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                      break;
                }




                byte[] pureData = new byte[packetSize];
                System.arraycopy(answer_buffer, 9, pureData, 0, packetSize);

                System.arraycopy(pureData, 0, archive, i*packetSize, packetSize);


                //float percentDiscrete = 100/32;


                //currentProgress = (int) (100 - (float) 100/progressCounter);
                //progressBar.setProgress(30);
                //percent.setText("Скачано: " + currentProgress);
                //if (currentProgress == 32)
                //{
                //  currentProgress = 1;
                //}
                //else
                //{
                //  currentProgress++;
                //}

            }



            // заполнение файла-контейнера ----------------------------------------------------
            /*
            fileContainer.add(archive);
            fileContainer.remove(0);

            try {

                for (int i = 0; i<60; i++)
                {
                    System.arraycopy(fileContainer.get(i), 0, _60_archives, archiveSize*i, archiveSize);
                }                   

                FileOutputStream fo = new FileOutputStream(file);
                fo.write(_60_archives);  
                fo.close();

            } catch (Exception e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                Toast.makeText(DeviceUARTContext, "Exception "+e, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
            */



            byte[] pointer = {0};

            try{


                // чтение, модификация и запись указателя на файл-контейнер и файла-контейнера
                if (periodCheckBox.isChecked())
                {
                    selectedItemNum = EEPROMSSpinner.getSelectedItemPosition();
                    fileContainer.set(EEPROMSSpinner.getSelectedItemPosition(), archive);
                }
                else
                {

                    FileInputStream pointerFileInput = new FileInputStream(pointerFile); 
                    pointerFileInput.read(pointer);
                    pointerFileInput.close();

                    fileContainer.set(pointer[0], archive);

                    pointer[0]++;
                    if (pointer[0] == 60)
                    {
                        pointer[0] = 0;
                    }
                    FileOutputStream pointerFileOutput = new FileOutputStream(pointerFile);
                    pointerFileOutput.write(pointer[0]);  
                    pointerFileOutput.close();

                }


                // запись обновлённого файла-контейнера                 
                for (int i = 0; i<60; i++)
                {
                    System.arraycopy(fileContainer.get(i), 0, _60_archives, archiveSize*i, archiveSize);
                }




                FileOutputStream fileOutput = new FileOutputStream(file);
                fileOutput.write(_60_archives);  
                fileOutput.close();

                // заполнение коллекции
                for (int i = 0; i < 60; i++)
                {
                    archive = Arrays.copyOfRange(_60_archives, i*archiveSize, i*archiveSize + archiveSize);
                    fileContainer.add(archive);
                }
                fillSpinner(v);



            }
            catch (Exception e) {

            }




            //----------------------------------------------------------------------------------




        }



    }); 









      }






}
```

Comment: Можно, покажи код полностью.

Comment: Судя по коду ошибки, ваш  MyTask является внутренним классом какого-то другого класса. А внутренние классы можно создавать, только имея обьект внешнего класса. Если так, то вам нужно вынести ваш  MyTask в отдельный файл.

Comment: Или сделать статическим, а то фрагменты статически, остальное нет... как-то все не правильно =)